# Modificar item "More" Tab Bar ios swift

Tags: ios, swift, swift2

He realizado una app con Tab Bar y cuando implemento mas de 6 item automáticamente crea el item "More".

¿Como modifico el titulo "More" y lo demas que esta en ingles?. Adjunto Imagenes.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Primero de todo una recomendación: el `UITabBar` está pensando para tener como máximo 5 items. Si necesitas muchos más, quizás deberías replantearte el diseño de la aplicación para acomodar todo de otra forma más simple para el usuario. Te puedo asegurar que los usuarios no entenderán donde están los tabs del `More`

Dicho esto, puedes hacer lo siguiente para cambiar el título del último tab:

```
if let viewController = tabController.viewControllers?[4] {
    viewController.tabBarItem.title = "Título del tab"
}
```